# Replacing all my 3 way lamp bulbs with 150W regular size incandescent?

Tags: light-fixture, light-bulb

A while ago, I got a bug up...and converted all my lamp sockets to 3 way (50/100/150 watt), even changing out the little brass holder thingies (many were already).

But now, I realized I actually hate 3 way lamps.  I NEVER use the 50 or 100 settings.  Always use the 150 or off.  Plus I learned how 3 way bulbs work (two filaments) and so it is impossible for the bulb to just go bad...one filament always goes first.

So anyways, was thinking I could just avoid changing all the little brass holder things back.  And just stick 150w bulbs in there.  I don't mind the clicking through issue (I think).

Anything wrong with this plan?

Also, I went to local big box and looked for 150W incandescents.  But could not find any that were normal size (were all oversized and won't work in some lamps).  Is this just my big box and I can find them on the net?  Would think if they can fit 150w thermally in a bulb with two filaments they can do it with one.  But I donno.

Lightbulb section of store has gotten very confusing to me now.  Hard to find normal bulbs.  If I had to do 150W LED or compact fluorescent maybe could do that...although light seems harsher.

Also, if you think I should just bit the bullet and change the little brass holders and not click through, let me know.  Or if I'm being silly and should just buy 3 way bulbs and change out when one filament fails.

Comment: Many countries have banned the sale of the ordinary incandescent on energy saving grounds. Check out the various varieties of LED that you can get: white, warm white etc

Comment: Why do you want specifically **150W incandescent**? That's the problem. You (and billions of others) have to **stop** shopping by power usage and change to shopping by **light produced**, which is measured in **lumens**. A 150W incandescent will get you ~ 2800 lumens.  A typical "150W equivalent" LED bulb might produce 2600 lumens, last 10x as long (or longer) and use 18W. At 0.20/kWh, the savings over the life of an incandescent bulb (let alone the full lifetime of an LED, with fewer bulb replacements) can be $20 or more! Far more than enough to pay for a super-high quality LED.

Comment: The reason you don't see many "real" 150W bulbs in the big box stores (or anywhere else, for that matter) is a combination of govt. push (via carrot (rebates for LEDs) or stick (regulation of incandescents) and market forces. It really doesn't matter if the LED bulb costs $10 instead of $1 for the incandescent, because the total cost of ownership is far lower for the LED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with putting a 1-way bulb in a 3-way socket. The only thing that may happen is that you have to turn the knob twice to turn the bulb on or off.

If you find CF or LED bulbs to be harsh, try “soft white” bulbs which are similar color to incandescent.

Answer (score 1):

As DoxyLover said, there's nothing wrong with a 1-way bulb in a 3-way socket.

Whether you stick with incandescent or switch to LED, you can use a double light adapter and use two bulbs in the lamp. So if you can't find 150s, you can use two 75s, or their lumen equivalents in LED.

[image]

[Photo credit](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-660-Watt-Double-Light-Socket-Adapter-Brown-128/302009542)

Comment: This likely moves the bulb closer to the housing or shade than the UL listing accommodates.